# console.log(data) to json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, xml

I'm working on one page with forms.

I need help with the JS script below

When I press SUBMIT I get data in console.log, but I want in json file on server, or xml data, but every time when I change something in the form to add new data in that file, not to create new file

Any help?

```js
;(function($) {
  $.fn.toJSON = function() {
    var $elements = {};
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name')
      var type = $(this).attr('type')
      if (name) {
        var $value;
        if (type == 'radio') {
          $value = $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked', $form).val()
        } else if (type == 'checkbox') {
          $value = $(this).is(':checked')
        } else {
          $value = $(this).val()
        }
        $elements[$(this).attr('name')] = $value
      }
    });
    return JSON.stringify($elements)
  };
  $.fn.fromJSON = function(json_string) {
    var $form = $(this)
    var data = JSON.parse(json_string)
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      var $elem = $('[name="' + key + '"]', $form)
      var type = $elem.first().attr('type')
      if (type == 'radio') {
        $('[name="' + key + '"][value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', true)
      } else if (type == 'checkbox' && (value == true || value == 'true')) {
        $('[name="' + key + '"]').prop('checked', true)
      } else {
        $elem.val(value)
      }
    })
  };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#_save").on('click', function() {
    console.log("Saving form data...")
    var data = $("form#test-form").toJSON()
    console.log(data);
    localStorage['form_data'] = data;

    return false;
  })

});
```

Comment: Look into AJAX/JSON - you will need a server process like PHP or similar

Comment: Javascript is a client-side language - it can't directly communicate with the server. You'd need to make an Ajax call to a server-side script which does those things.

Comment: What's your server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can easily serialise form like this:

```
$("form-selector").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form_data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(form_data);
});
```

From your post, it is not totally clear what you want to do with the serialised form data. If you want to post that data to the server and save it as a file then this is a totally different topic. You didn't provide any info regarding your server-side technology - is it PHP, .NET, nodeJS, Python, ...

Well anyway... regardless your server-side technology you can post serialised data by jQuery's post method (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
let some_data = {field_name: 'Some name', field_surname: 'some surename', field_other: 'some other data'};
let jqxhr = $.post("http://example-host.com/service.php", some_data)
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert("finished");
  });
```

And altogether (client side JS):

```
$("form-selector").on("submit", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    let form_data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log('Form data', form_data);

    let posting = $.post("http://example-host.com/service.php", form_data);

    posting.done(function() {
        console.log("Form data ajax post - success");
    });

    posting.fail(function() {
        console.log("Form data ajax post - error");
    });

    posting.always(function() {
        alert("Form data ajax post - finished");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Already did serialize data from form

this is form

```
<form id="test-form"">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <h2><strong>Scan Vehicle Barcode</strong></h2>
                        <p>Click the <strong>button</strong> next to the input-field to start scanning an barcode</p>
                </a>
                <div class="pos-f-t">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
                          <div class="bg-primary p-4">
                            <a href="/" ></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="input-field">
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                        <label for="isbn_input">EAN:</label>
                        <input id="isbn_input" class="isbn" type="text" name="barcode" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 scan"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>&nbsp;Scan Barcode</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="vehiclecategory" id="inlineRadio1" value="CHASSIS">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">CHASSIS</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="vehiclecategory" id="inlineRadio2" value="SCATTOLINI">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">SCATTOLINI</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="vehiclecategory" id="inlineRadio3" value="VAN">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">VAN</label>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1">Position:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="trainposition">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>A</option>
                                <option>B</option>
                                <option>C</option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1">Wagon:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="wagonposition">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option>34</option>
                                    <option>35</option>
                                    <option>36</option>
                                    <option>37</option>
                                    <option>38</option>
                                    <option>39</option>
                                    <option>40</option>
                                    <option>41</option>
                                    <option>42</option>
                                    <option>43</option>
                                    <option>44</option>
                                    <option>45</option>
                                    <option>46</option>
                                    <option>47</option>
                                    <option>48</option>
                                    <option>49</option>
                                    <option>50</option>
                                    <option>51</option>
                                    <option>52</option>
                                    <option>53</option>
                                    <option>54</option>
                                    <option>55</option>
                                    <option>56</option>
                                    <option>57</option>
                                    <option>58</option>
                                    <option>59</option>
                                    <option>60</option>
                                    <option>61</option>
                                    <option>62</option>
                                    <option>63</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    <input type='submit' id='_save' value='SUBMIT THE VEHICLE' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Simple Barcode scanner and collecting some data.

All of this is working well, and my data is saved in console.log()

I want that data from console.log to be saved in some file like .json or .xml

server-side nodeJS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TX2L.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6h15.png)